# Url to a NewForm with a specific content type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, url, newform

I have a SharePoint 2010 Site collection and I need to know how I would write the URLs to a newform.aspx associated with a SharePoint list when I have two separate content types.

Generally (for a single content type) I would do it like this:

```
Sitecollection.com/lists/myListName/NewForm.aspx
```

..but this only displays the ***default*** content type.

I'm am sure there is a simple add-on to the URL to define the other content type but I simply don't know it and I cant find the answer in my resources so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass content type id as query string parameter `ContentTypeId`

```
Sitecollection.com/lists/myListName/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x0100123456789
```

You can easily find your content type id if you go to List settings, click on desired content type and find the id in URL (here it is called `ctype` parameter)