# How to redirect a "newform" using a content type that already has "source" appended to the URL?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Newform pages using a content type already appends ?source= to the URL to utilize a content type but since I normally use ?Source to redirect the newform page after a submit how can I do that when ?Source is already being used by the content type?
Can you append a Source URL To a Source URL? Doesn't sound plausible.
Thing is I cannot remove the ?Source part of the URL since it is used for a content type. How do I redirect this page?

Comment: **?** declares the URL has parameters, so there is ONE **?**. All subsequent parameters are separated by **&**

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Naturally it was here all along! :)
How did I miss it?
[Url to a NewForm with a specific content type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135497/url-to-a-newform-with-a-specific-content-type)

Thank you Vedran Rasol!

Comment: Oh and THEN add the ?Source link. :) I love it when it works out.

Comment: If you want to execute code on the From depending on the ContentTypeId: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198499/conditionally-display-a-cewp-depending-on-form-content-type